# Mate Dispatcher tag

Tags: apache-flex, mate

I need to pass a variable in dispatcher tag... for instance

```
var google:EventName = new EventName(EventName.ADD_User,user);
dispatchEvent(google);
```

Now when i go to Mate dispatcher tag... how can i pass the value user.

```
  <mate:Dispatcher id="myDispatcher" generator="{EventName}" 
type="{EventName.ADD_User}">
                      <mate:eventProperties>
                                       <mate:EventProperties
                                                          myProperty="myValue"
                                                          myProperty2="100" />
                      </mate:eventProperties>
    </mate:Dispatcher>
```

Now how can i pass the user in the mate dispatcher tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to declare user as a property of your GoogleEvent.as class. For GoogleEvent.as:

```
package
{
  public class GoogleEvent extends Event
  {
    public static const ADD_User:String = "GoogleEvent_AddUser";

    public var user:String;

    public function GoogleEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
      super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
  }
}
```

And in your event declaration:

```
var google:GoogleEvent= new GoogleEvent(GoogleEvent.ADD_User);

google.user = "My User's Name";
dispatchEvent(google);
```

Then to get the user value from your event in your Event Map:

```
<EventHandlers type="{ GoogleEvent.ADD_User }">
  <MethodInvoker generator="{ MyTargetPresentaionModel }" method="DoSomething" arguments="{ [event.user] }" />
</EventHandlers>
```

Let me know if you have any questions. I hope this helps!